AWS Kinesis Video Stream
I am trying to use kinesis video, my project is a react project, I have installed aws amplify and I have installed aws-sdk, I am trying to stream video but I can't find a clear example of how to do it, what I have seen is that I can do it mediate putMedia but I get the error that putMedia is not a function of KinesisVideo, this is an example of what I am trying:
const sendVideoFrameToAWS = useCallback(() => {
    if (webcamRef.current) {
      const imageSrc = webcamRef.current.getScreenshot({ width: widthConstraint, height: heightConstraint });
      if (imageSrc !== null) {
        const imageData = atob(imageSrc.split(',')[1]);
        const imageBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(imageData.length);
        const uint8Array = new Uint8Array(imageBuffer);
        for (let i = 0; i < imageData.length; i++) {
          uint8Array[i] = imageData.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        const params = {
          StreamName: 'demo',
          Data: uint8Array
        };

        const kinesisVideo = new AWS.KinesisVideo({
          region: 'someRegion',
          accessKeyId: 'someAccessKeyId',
          secretAccessKey: 'someSecretAccessKey'
        });

        kinesisVideo.createStream({ StreamName: 'demoStream' }, (err, data) => {
          if (err) {
            console.error('Error creating stream:', err);
          } else {
            console.log('Stream created successfully:', data);
            const client = new AWS.KinesisVideoArchivedMedia({ region: 'us-east-2' });
            const kinesisVideoStreams = new AWS.KinesisVideoArchivedMedia({ region: 'us-east-2' });
            const params = {
              StreamName: streamName,
              DataEndpoint: data.DataEndpoint
            };
            kinesisVideoStreams.putMedia(params, (err, data) => {
              if (err) {
                console.error('Error putting media:', err);
              } else {
                console.log('Media put successfully:', data);
              }
            });
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }, [webcamRef, widthConstraint, heightConstraint]);

Could you help me on what I am doing wrong please.
I tried get putMedia from differnts classes from kinesis but does not work
